# How to configure TestCafe Quarantine Mode to pass if there is at least 1 successful execution?

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

As per TestCafe Quarantine Mode documentation, I can see this is the default behaviour:

"*The most frequent outcome is recorded as the test result.*"

I'd like to configure Quarantine Mode to pass if there is at least 1 successful execution (even if majority of runs failed).

Is there any way (or workaround) to achieve this?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't see a way to configure it. You would probably have to edit the source to make that happen somewhere in this file: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/blob/master/src/runner/test-run-controller.js. If you got it working, maybe you could get it merged back into TestCafe for everyone to enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

We will consider your suggestion ("... at least 1 successful execution") in this issue: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/3891. Please stay tuned to our updates there.

Answer (score 1):

It is now possible, like this:

```sh
testcafe chrome ./tests/ -q attemptLimit=5,successThreshold=2
```

See docs: https://testcafe.io/documentation/402830/guides/basic-guides/run-tests#quarantine-mode